# SuperSet Gamma users can't see their own charts

Tags: charts, dashboard, apache-superset

On SuperSet (0.38.0), all our users have the following roles :

- `Gamma`
- `sql_lab`
- custom role `DB_ACCESS` : `database access on [Timescaledb XXX].(id:3)`
- custom role `tables_modify` : `[can edit on TableModelView, can add on TableModelView, can list on TableModelView, can show on TableModelView, can tables on Superset, refresh on TableModelView, can save on Datasource, can get on Datasource, can datasources on Superset, menu access on Tables, can list on TableColumnInlineView, can show on TableColumnInlineView, can fetch datasource metadata on Superset]`

These users can :

- create charts, add them to dashboard
- see dashboards
- see charts in dashboards and edit them from there

But they cannot see their own Charts listed in Charts Menu.

Is this the expected behaviour? Is there some other permission we need to add in order for users to see their own charts?

Comment: Menu Access on Charts seems to be missing. Perhaps that?

Comment: Menu access on Charts is part of Gamma role

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been following me for a very long time. The problem is that superset has a very limited documentation and its access control model is mostly based on FAB which is pretty hard to use by end users. All that remains is to try to add different permission to a role until you get desired result. I've found out that missing permission is `schema access on [database].[schema]`. After a role is granted that perm, users are able to see created datasources autamitically. Have fun!